# Trying to create a follow-up intent to capture contact information

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to create an intent for personal follow-up with anonymous visitors. I have created a "getfollowup" intent that triggers when visitor asks for escalation, speak to a manager, etc. I want to create yes/no follow-up intents and trigger a "getcontact" intent for "yes" answer. The getcontact intent is created to capture @sys.given-name and @sys.email for slot filling. I'm having trouble getting the two intents to connect. Here's an example of how I'd like the conversation to flow:

...
Visitor: I need to speak to a manager

[getfollowup intent triggered]

Response: Sorry I haven't been able to help. Would you like me to have someone reach out to you?

Visitor: Yes

[getfollowup-yes context]

[need to trigger getcontact intent here...it is this transition that I can't figure out]

Response: Ok. First may have your name?

Visitor: John

Response: Thanks, John. May I have your email address?

Vistor: john@example.com

Response: Thanks for the info. Someone will reach out to you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't "trigger" an Intent. Intents capture *what the user says*, and *not* what you do with that.

So the approach in your case would that when the user says "yes", you simply prompt them for the information you want and set a Context indicating you want this information.

You can then create other Intents (such as your "getcontact" Intent) that take this as an Input Context and have the user providing the information you've prompted for.